# .EXE getting stuck after closing program with red X button built in to WPF program

Tags: exit, forceclose

I'm sure this is being caused by one of the loops not shutting down right but i could be wrong. i know the X should close it all the way but it just gets stuck open.
I have tried to make it exit with out using the default X built in but it does not work, I would like to use the normal exit function but it just hangs open on my pc. I am having to reboot to get it to close. not even closing the process tree will close it out.

```
using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Windows;
        using System.Windows.Controls;
        using System.Windows.Data;
        using System.Windows.Documents;
        using System.Windows.Input;
        using System.Windows.Media;
        using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
        using System.Windows.Navigation;
        using System.Windows.Shapes;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
        using System.IO;
        using System.Timers;
        using System.Threading;

        namespace Verifone_note_secure {
            /// <summary>
            /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
            /// </summary>
            public partial class MainWindow : Window {
                public MainWindow() {
                    InitializeComponent();

                    richTextBox1.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
                    richTextBox2.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
                    richTextBox3.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
                    richTextBox4.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
                    richTextBox5.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
                    richTextBox6.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
                    textBox1.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;


                    Style noSpaceStyle = new Style(typeof(Paragraph));
                    noSpaceStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Paragraph.MarginProperty, new Thickness(0)));
                    richTextBox1.Resources.Add(typeof(Paragraph), noSpaceStyle);
                    richTextBox2.Resources.Add(typeof(Paragraph), noSpaceStyle);
                    richTextBox3.Resources.Add(typeof(Paragraph), noSpaceStyle);
                    richTextBox4.Resources.Add(typeof(Paragraph), noSpaceStyle);
                    richTextBox5.Resources.Add(typeof(Paragraph), noSpaceStyle);
                    richTextBox6.Resources.Add(typeof(Paragraph), noSpaceStyle);

                    textBox1.FontSize = 20;

                    Application.Current.MainWindow.Closing += new CancelEventHandler(MainWindow_Closing);
                    dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
                    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 140);
                    dispatcherTimer.Start();
                }

                System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
                private int iScroll;
                private string strString;
                StreamReader reader;
                StreamWriter writer;


                private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                    try {
                        reader = File.OpenText(@"ScrollingText.txt");
                        strString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        if (strString.Length <= 1) {
                            reader.Close();
                            writer = File.CreateText(@"ScrollingText.txt");
                            writer.Write("      Please Enter your text into ScrollingText.txt for it to give you your personal messages      ");
                            writer.Close();
                            reader = File.OpenText(@"ScrollingText.txt");
                            strString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    } catch {
                        writer = File.CreateText(@"ScrollingText.txt");
                        writer.Write("      Please Enter your text into ScrollingText.txt for it to give you your personal messages      ");
                        writer.Close();
                        reader = File.OpenText(@"ScrollingText.txt");
                        strString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                    iScroll = iScroll + 1;
                    int iLmt = strString.Length - iScroll;
                    if (iLmt < 56) {
                        iScroll = 0;
                    }
                    string str = strString.Substring(iScroll, 56);
                    label2.Content = str;
                }

                void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {// when form closes
                    reader.Close();
                }

                private void KB_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("");
                }

                private void VeriWeb_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("");
                }

                private void Critrix_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("");
                }

                private void AmDocs_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("");
                }

                private void preescalationchecklist_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("");
                }

                private void Clearpumpsonhold_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("");
                }

                private void Clearreservedpumps_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("");
                }

                private void DCRPollError_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("");
                }

                private void DCRHold_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("");
                }

                private void Topazstuckonwhitescreen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("");
                }

                private void UnabletologintoTopaz_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("");
                }

                private void Remoteserviceisdown_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("");
                }

                private void MX8xxpinpadcommunications_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("");
                }

                private void Monthlyclosestopsprinting_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("");
                }

                private void CommanderPuTTYcommands_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("");
                }

                private void COMMANDERECpleasechecksystemwdt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("[enter image description here][1]");
                }

                private void fuelcommerrornofuelfunctionsnow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("");
                }

                private void posfuelandsalesquickreference_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("");
                }

                private void commanderfueldcrconfiguration_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("");
                }

                private void T3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Clear();
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("");
                }

                private void ResponsetoVASCreturningcall_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Clear();
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("");
                }

                private void PinPadERS_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Clear();
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("");
                }

                private void ValeroCSTdispatchrequest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Clear();
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("");
                }

                private void PantryDispatchRequest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Clear();
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("");
                }

                private void GeneralDispatchTemplate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Clear();
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("");
                }

                private void sppdispatch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Clear();
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("");
                }

                private void DialInT2Template_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Clear();
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("");
                }

                private void VantageTemplate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Clear();
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("");
                }

                private void exxon_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    Clipboard.SetText(Regex.Replace(exxon.Header.ToString(), "[A-Za-z : ]", ""));
                }

                private void ShellVantage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    Clipboard.SetText(Regex.Replace(ShellVantage.Header.ToString(), "[A-Za-z : ]", ""));
                }

                private void Shell_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    Clipboard.SetText(Regex.Replace(Shell.Header.ToString(), "[A-Za-z : ]", "").Remove(12));
                }

                private void Plenti_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    Clipboard.SetText(Regex.Replace(Plenti.Header.ToString(), "[A-Za-z : ]", ""));
                }

                private void Worldpay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    Clipboard.SetText(Regex.Replace(Worldpay.Header.ToString(), "[A-Za-z : ]", ""));
                }

                private void Hughe_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    Clipboard.SetText(Regex.Replace(Hughe.Header.ToString(), "[A-Za-z : ]", ""));
                }

                private void Chevron_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    Clipboard.SetText(Regex.Replace(Chevron.Header.ToString(), "[A-Za-z : ]", "").Remove(12));
                }

                private void Mako_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    Clipboard.SetText(Regex.Replace(Mako.Header.ToString(), "[A-Za-z : ]", ""));
                }

                private void PCcommander_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    richTextBox5.AppendText("Power cycled Commander ");
                }

                private void PCFCI_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    richTextBox5.AppendText("Power cycled Forecourt Controller ");
                }

                private void PCEZR_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    richTextBox5.AppendText("Power cycled Enhanced Zone Router ");
                }

                private void PCsapphire_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    richTextBox5.AppendText("Power cycle Sapphire ");
                }

                private void initDCR_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    richTextBox5.AppendText("Initialized Dispenser Card reader ");
                }

                private void initFuel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    richTextBox5.AppendText("Initialized Fuel ");
                }

                private void reseatCables_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    richTextBox5.AppendText("Reseated Cables ");
                }

                private void accessedPutty_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    richTextBox5.AppendText("Accessed site via PuTTY @ ");
                }

                private void configCheck_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    richTextBox5.AppendText("Check Configuration Client ");
                }

                private void CNG_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    richTextBox6.AppendText("Case number Given ");
                }

                private void CND_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    richTextBox6.AppendText("Case number Declined ");
                }

                private void CFcheckTR_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    richTextBox5.AppendText("CFcheck on Topaz/Ruby ");
                }

                private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { //copy all button
                    string CopyAll = "";
                    string NewLine = "\n";
                    richTextBox2.SelectAll();
                    richTextBox3.SelectAll();
                    richTextBox4.SelectAll();
                    richTextBox5.SelectAll();
                    richTextBox6.SelectAll();
                    CopyAll += richTextBox2.Selection.Text + NewLine + richTextBox3.Selection.Text + NewLine + richTextBox4.Selection.Text + NewLine + richTextBox5.Selection.Text + NewLine + richTextBox6.Selection.Text;
                    Clipboard.SetText(CopyAll);
                }

                private void button7_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {//clear all button
                    //if (System.DateTime.Now > new System.DateTime(2015, 10, 30)) {
                    //    MessageBox.Show("Please contact tech support, for new trial version", "Trial Expired!!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                    //    Application.Current.Shutdown();
                    //}

                    if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to Clear All?\nThis includes the clipboard", "Warning!", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Warning) == MessageBoxResult.Yes) {
                        richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Clear();
                        richTextBox2.Document.Blocks.Clear();
                        richTextBox3.Document.Blocks.Clear();
                        richTextBox4.Document.Blocks.Clear();
                        richTextBox5.Document.Blocks.Clear();
                        richTextBox6.Document.Blocks.Clear();
                        textBox1.Clear();
                        Clipboard.Clear();
                    }
                }

                private void button8_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {//copy name 
                    textBox1.SelectAll();
                    textBox1.Copy();
                }

                private void button9_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {//copy template area
                    richTextBox1.SelectAll();
                    richTextBox1.Copy();
                }

                private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {//copy box 1
                    richTextBox2.SelectAll();
                    richTextBox2.Copy();
                }

                private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {//copy box 2
                    richTextBox3.SelectAll();
                    richTextBox3.Copy();
                }

                private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {//copy box 3
                    richTextBox4.SelectAll();
                    richTextBox4.Copy();
                }

                private void button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {//copy box 4
                    richTextBox5.SelectAll();
                    richTextBox5.Copy();
                }

                private void button6_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {//copy box 5
                    richTextBox6.SelectAll();
                    richTextBox6.Copy();
                }

                private void button10_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                    RichTextBox[] rTextBox = { richTextBox1, richTextBox2, richTextBox3, richTextBox4, richTextBox5, richTextBox6 };

                    overallTextReplace(rTextBox);
                }
                public void overallTextReplace(RichTextBox[] rtb) {
                    string[] keyword = { "FCI", "CND", "CNG", "DCR", "EZR", "VASC", "PC", "SFC" };
                    string[] newString = { "Forecourt Controller", "Case Number Declined ", "Case Number Given", "Dispenser Card reader", "Enhanced Zone Router", "Verifone Authorized Service Contractor", "Power cycle", "Smart Fuel Controller" };
                    for (int i = 0; i < rtb.Length; i++) {
                        RichTextBox rtb_wording = rtb[i];
                        var textRange = new TextRange(rtb_wording.Document.ContentStart, rtb_wording.Document.ContentEnd);
                        string rtf;
                        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
                            textRange.Save(memoryStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
                            rtf = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
                        }
                        for (int j = 0; j < keyword.Length; j++) {
                            rtf = rtf.Replace(keyword[j], newString[j]);
                        }
                        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(rtf));
                        rtb_wording.SelectAll();
                        rtb_wording.Selection.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried to upload a picture of the application being stuck but would not let me, let me know if you need a picture and i can provide one

Comment: anyone? i still need help